# AsyncTaks HTTP-request timeouts and exception handling

Tags: java, android

I'm making HTTP-get requests to the Facebook graph API.

In about 1/5 times my code never gets to `Log.i("debug", "resp");`. No exception thrown. Shouldn't it? Or is it just a very long timeout by default?

If I add a custom timeout (see below), I get to throw an exception. But even though my code is wrapped in a try+catch statement, my app crashes (just like on any unhandled exceptions), instead of letting me handle the error in `onPostExecute()`. Why dont I end up in the method?

```
protected Map<String, Integer> doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    try {

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://graph.facebook.com/....etc");

        //final HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
        //HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
        //HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        Log.i("debug", "resp");  

        HttpEntity resEntityGet = response.getEntity();

        //do stuff with resEntityGet           

        return result;            

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, Integer> result) {

    if(result != null){
        //use the result data
    } else {
        //exception occured
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious... why not use the Facebook SDK for Android?

Comment: @borges Don't know. I'm new to Android development and didnt see the need for it. It's pretty simple to parse json with the Gson libraty. But for a more advanced app than this I would probably use it :)

Comment: Can you print your exception in the catch block? Perhaps that will give you a hint?

Comment: @AbuZubair See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a `Toast` from the `doInBackground` method if you post it to the UI thread. There's a few ways to do it, but here's one way:

```
mainActivity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} );
```

You'll need to make the `Exception` variable `final`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Turns out that you can't create toasts in `doInBackground()`. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Try Log.d("xxx", "xxx"); and view it in logcat

Comment: Exactly Toast cannot be added to doInBackground() method instead you can add it to onPostExecute() method but since you was using it to show the error message I suggest that you use Log Object.

Comment: Json Robinson said the same thing with description.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same problem that time i handle exception  this way

```
public class ServerCheckingActvity extends Activity{
    ProgressDialog  progress;
    static String constant="";
    Map<String, Integer> result;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     new MyAsynchTask().execute();
}

private  class MyAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
           progress=new ProgressDialog(ServerCheckingActvity.this);
           // progress.setTitle(" DATA RETRIVEING");
            progress.setMessage("please wait........");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progress.setCancelable(true);
            progress.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String view="";

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("www.facebook .com/...........");

            //final HttpParams httpParams = httpclient.getParams();
            //HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
            //HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);

            HttpResponse response =httpClient.execute(get);
            Log.i("debug", "resp");  

            HttpEntity resEntityGet = response.getEntity();

            //do stuff with resEntityGet           

           // assigen ur value to result map object here;    
            result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


        } catch (Exception e) { 
            constant="Exception";
            //Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Error: " + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //return null;
        }
        return view="from doing background";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String view ){
        if(constant=="Exception"){
            constant="";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "server problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else if(result != null){
            //use the result data
        } else {
            //exception occured
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (Exception ex) {
       // execep is here string variable u declare in globally
       execep=ex.getMessage();
      runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
   @Override
public void run() {
  Toast.makeText(  getApplicationContext(), "Error: " +execep, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }} );

                               }//catch
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but it's not clearly and safe. If you do not set up timeout, it is set default value 0. A timeout value of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout. In that case , when response data has problem because of anything, your client either is interrupted or do not know anything. In case 2 - worse case - client will not throw any exception and your program will live forever.
Resolve for this problem, you should set timeout when get or post everything to server. It's safe.
I do not exactly know the cause client lives forever without any exception. I think it it a server problem or network problem.
Hope can help you.